# Android tap URL opens modified URL

Tags: android, url, filter

I am completely new to Java and Android programming. I have installed Android Studio and played around with some examples. I need to implement a simple application that

1) Android offers as an alternative to Firefox or Chrome when tapping an http URL,

2) filters and modifies the tapped URL (via simple `dirname` and `concat` operations) and opens the result in a browser.

In bash, something like `firefox "$(filmod $1)"` would do the job (for some suitable implementation of `filmod`), but how would this look like in Java and Android Studio? Thanks, nbpf

Answer (score 1):

For the first question take a look at this link http://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html  in short, you need to set an intent filter/handler.

Using Android Studio, create helloWorld project and make this changes to that app.

1 question (this will make your app appear on the list with mozila,chrome... when you click on some link on your phone):

In your manifset add this lines INSIDE "activity" tags.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

2 question:

In MainActivity, onCreate() callback function, put this code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    String link = intent.getScheme();
    String linkData = intent.getDataString();

    Log.d("TMS","action is: " + action);
    Log.d("TMS","link is: " + link);
    Log.d("TMS","linkData is: " + linkData);
```

String linkData is your URL name. There you have your link in String format and you can pass it to textView, or WebView...etc... I have tested this on Android 5.1 but I don`t see any reason that it shouldn`t work on API 10 until API 23.

If you want, I can share you the project I tested this on.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Let me assume that I have managed to solve 1) and, upon tapping a URL, I have the option of starting my application. At this point, my main difficulty with 2) is how to get the URL that has triggered the opening of the application in a local variable. From there, I guess I can figure out how to operate on it.